# How to use 'logit_bias' parameter of model.predict in VertexAI Python SDK?

Tags: python, large-language-model, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to generate responses from a pretrained language model in Google's Vertex AI API with a heavy bias to include certain tokens, so I believe I want to use the logit_bias parameter as I would with OpenAI models.

(Based on the documentation, the argument might be called logitBias or logit_bias. The latter is what appears in the code base https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/tree/main)

When I pass this argument, the model throws an error about data types. When I remove the argument everything else runs fine, but obviously doesn't have the desired bias for certain tokens.

I am running the code below, which is based on the examples aside from adding in parameters.

```
    from google.cloud import aiplatform
    import vertexai
    from vertexai.language_models import TextGenerationModel, ChatModel


    def interview(temperature: float, project_id: str, location: str, prompts):
        """Ideation example with a Large Language Model"""

        aiplatform.init(project=project_id, location=location)

        parameters = {
            "temperature": temperature,  # Temperature controls the degree of randomness in token selection.
            "max_output_tokens": 1,  # Token limit determines the maximum amount of text output.
            "logprobs": 5,
            "logit_bias": {33:99.9,34:99.9}, 
            "top_p": 0.2,  # Tokens are selected from most probable to least until the sum of their probabilities equals the top_p value.
            "top_k": .8,  # A top_k of 1 means the selected token is the most probable among all tokens.
        }

        model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained("text-bison@002")

        logits = []

        for p in prompts:
            response = model.predict(p, **parameters)
            print(f"Response from Model: {response.text}")
            tlp = response._prediction_response.predictions[0]['logprobs']['topLogProbs']
            print(tlp)
            logits.append(tlp)


        return logits
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/example.py", line 107, in <module>
    response = interview(temperature, project_id, location, batch['questions'])
  File "/home/username/example.py", line 32, in interview
    response = model.predict(p, **parameters)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vertexai/language_models/_language_models.py", line 1036, in predict
    prediction_response = self._endpoint.predict(
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py", line 1579, in predict
    prediction_response = self._prediction_client.predict(
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/prediction_service/client.py", line 593, in predict
    request.parameters = parameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/message.py", line 787, in __setattr__
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 228, in to_proto
    pb_value = self.get_rule(proto_type=proto_type).to_proto(value)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/utils/enhanced_library/_decorators.py", line 33, in to_proto
    return super().to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/rules/struct.py", line 82, in to_proto
    struct_value=self._marshal.to_proto(struct_pb2.Struct, value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 228, in to_proto
    pb_value = self.get_rule(proto_type=proto_type).to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/rules/struct.py", line 139, in to_proto
    fields={
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/rules/struct.py", line 140, in <dictcomp>
    k: self._marshal.to_proto(struct_pb2.Value, v) for k, v in value.items()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 228, in to_proto
    pb_value = self.get_rule(proto_type=proto_type).to_proto(value)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/utils/enhanced_library/_decorators.py", line 33, in to_proto
    return super().to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/rules/struct.py", line 82, in to_proto
    struct_value=self._marshal.to_proto(struct_pb2.Struct, value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 228, in to_proto
    pb_value = self.get_rule(proto_type=proto_type).to_proto(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/proto/marshal/rules/struct.py", line 138, in to_proto
    answer = struct_pb2.Struct(
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```